# Cannot delete an added site from Google account after being registered on Google website translator

Tags: google-search-console, google-translate

I can't seem to delete a site that I added on my Google account. When I login
at [here](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/) it displays that I am the owner/editor of the site but wherever I look, I can't seem to find a *delete site* function.

*See screenshot* (click image to view larger):

[image: google translation]

Comment: I'd never used Google Website Translator before.  I added a site to it to test it and could not find a way to remove it either.

Comment: thanks for the time.. i really wish i could get a way to do this though.. i already transferred the site to my client but my own site is still tied to it. I just want to get over with it.

Answer (score 6):

I have been to this issue once! Yes, indeed it's really hard to find a way to get rid of this site reference under Google Translation. But, man made everything can be controlled  ;-)

Simply Click on [here](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/list?hl=en#translations/active),  go to "Tools" > "Translation Memories" >> Remove your site reference...

Comment: hi, seems my account has a bug since I was able to use the website translator service yet i cannot get to the toolkit. Google says "We are sorry, but you do not have access to this service. Please contact your domain administrator for access."

Answer (score 2):

On the Google Webmaster screen that first pops up when you log-in to Google Webmaster Tools which asks you to select a site. On the same line with the website name, all the way to the right there is a button that says 'Manage Site' click this button and you will be prompted with a drop-down menu which has the option to 'Delete Site'.

[image: The button and drop-down menu are highlighted in blue for you]

Comment: sorry but this is not google webmaster tools, it's on google translate. you can check the difference in urls from my screen shot. thanks for the effort though. i really appreciate it!